# New career or job after ending former on a low note

Tags: interviewing, applications

I ended my former job (and career) on a low note, which can be explained by a gradual loss of interest in the job. I produced some good work, but over time, I didn't see a future with the same work (dead-end), same career, and it began to show. My output became mediocre and then just the minimum necessary (at which point I decided to leave for a new career.) At best, I'll get a neutral reference on my performance. How do you transition to a new career and recover from one that ended on a low note?

Comment: Hi Michelle, I encourage you to [edit] this to provide some more details about the situation to give it some context. This is definitely a problem that Workplace SE can provide answers to. Hope this helps! :)